# Blender 3.6 - hair clump mask by texture using geometry nodes

Tags: hair

How to mask clumps using a texture instead of vertex groups?

`Interpolate Hair Curves` has something like this for masking. Would be great to have it for `Clump Hair Curves` as well.

[image]

[image]